# Turn off a function on mouseover - Javascript, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I am trying to create a content div with button links on a right sidebar. When the user is not hovering over any of the buttons, the content should rotate through each of the five button topics (I've accomplished this). Also, when the user hovers over a specific button, what should happen is a) stop the rotation and b) display only the content topic related to that button.

Currently all I can make it do is rotate through the topics (with a Javascript function) and make content appear and disappear on hover (in HTML). Help please?

```
<script>
function rotatecontent(){
curcontentindex=(curcontentindex<messages.length-1)? curcontentindex+1 : 0
prevcontentindex=(curcontentindex==0)? messages.length-1 : curcontentindex-1
futcontentindex=(curcontentindex==0)? messages.length-1 : curcontentindex+1
messages[prevcontentindex].style.display="none"
messages[curcontentindex].style.display="block"
messages[futcontentindex].style.display="none"
}


window.onload=function(){
if (document.all || document.getElementById){
getElementByClass("dyncontent")
setInterval("rotatecontent()", 1000)
}
}

$('#container li').hover(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}, function() {
    interval = setInterval("rotatecontent()", 1000);
});

</script>
```

HTML:

```
 <body>


 <ul id="container">

 <li><a href="#">
 <img src="image1.jpg" width="250" height="100" class="Bab-
 image"></a></li>


 <li><a href="#"><img src="image2.jpg" class="sluotr-image 
 </a></li>

 <li><a href="#"><img src="image3.jpg" 
 class="blogs-image"></a></li>

 <li><a href="#"><img src="image4.jpg" class="chat-
 image"></a></li>

 <li><a href="#"><img src="image5.jpg" 
 class="view-image"></a>
 </li>

 </ul>

 <div class="dyncontent">
 <div id="div1">Content 1</div>
 <div id="div2" style="display:none">Content 2</div>
 <div id="div3" style="display:none">Content 3</div>
 <div id="div4" style="display:none">Content 4</div>
 <div id="div5" style="display:none">Content 5</div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Your js and a bit of markup would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a jsfiddle rotates until you hover over one of the hyperlinks, then resumes when you leave: http://jsfiddle.net/58pms/11/ (updated jsfiddle, original only went through one rotation)

I feel like it's hard to say what's wrong with your original code since I had to add some variable declarations and HTML that were missing from your sample. I also took out the event handlers that would show the item you were hovering over for simplicity since I don't think that was your main question.

The HTML:

```
<ul id="container" overflow:hidden>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="dyncontent">
<div id="div1">Be A Billiken</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">Be A Billiken 2</div>
<div id="div3" style="display:none">Be A Billiken 3</div>
<div id="div4" style="display:none">Be A Billiken 4</div>
<div id="div5" style="display:none">Be A Billiken 5</div>
</div>
```

And the script:

```
var messages;
var curcontentindex = 0;
var prevcontentindex;
var futcontentindex;
var i;

function rotatecontent() {
    messages.hide();
    curcontentindex = (curcontentindex < messages.length - 1) ? curcontentindex + 1 : 0;
    messages.get(curcontentindex).style.display = "block";
}


$(function() {
    messages = $('.dyncontent').find('div');
    i = setInterval(rotatecontent, 1000);


    $('#container li').hover(function() {
        clearInterval(i);
    }, function() {
        i = setInterval(rotatecontent, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: This definitely does what I need, but for some reason I can't get it to work in my own document. I'll keep modifying my HTML and see what happens. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the variable `interval` outside of `window.onload function` to make it a `global` variable (so it can be accessed by other functions), i.e.

```
var interval=0;
window.onload=function(){
    // other code goes here
    interval=setInterval(rotatecontent, 1000); // use the variable here
}
```

or make overall changes as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function rotatecontent(){ 
        // Your function's code here 
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var interval=setInterval(rotatecontent, 1000);

        $('#container li img').hover(function() {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }, function() {
            interval = setInterval(rotatecontent, 1000);
        });
    }​);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the rotation still doesn't stop when I hover over the button.

Comment: Is not this `$('#container li')` your elements to hover ?

Comment: Where is your buttons in your html, i thought you were talking about `li`s ?

Comment: I am, the buttons are inside the <li>s.

Comment: Are you talking about images inside li ?

Comment: Where is `container` ? Can you post proper HTML ?

Comment: Yes, the images inside li, and I've posted HTML.

Comment: I tried the second solution and now the rotation and the hovering has stopped working.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use window.onload when you're already using jQuery. Use

```
$(function() { } );
```

instead.

Comment: Pro tip for SO users: if you mark something down, and your reason isn't immediately clear, please oh please provide some reasoning for down voting replies.

Comment: I think it's obvious that this answer doesn't offer a solution to the question; it's more of a general statement/suggestion (and no, I'm not the "downvoter").

Comment: Me neither but you could have commented this.

Comment: I honestly wrote about half of this AS a comment but then realized there wouldn't be any decent formatting in the comment section. :P